# FLWOR in Sql server count number of hits

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, xquery, xquery-sql, flwor

I am using SQL Server 2008 R2. My problem is that I want to count number of hits that i receive from XQuery query using FLWOR. For each hit, I want a consecutive number, like: 0,1,2,3,4...

My query:

```
select @xml.query('for $s at $count in /Root/Persons/Person
return <Person ID="{$count}">{$s}</Person>')
```

The only problem here is this is not supported in SQL Server and I receive an error:

```
Msg 9335, Level 16, State 1, Line 16
XQuery [query()]: The XQuery syntax 'at' is not supported.
```

I've also tried with let keyword and define new variable but I don't know how to increase value of that variable with each iteration?

Thanks for all the answers, Frenky

Answer (score 6, accepted):

XQuery is a declarative language, [you cannot use `let` to increment a counter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10295046/695343).

A rather hackish workaround to the missing `at` feature would be to count the preceding sibling `<person/>` tags:

```
for $person in /Root/Persons/Person
let $count := count($person/preceding-sibling::Person) + 1
return <Person ID="{$count}">{$person}</Person>
```

Be aware that this code will have `O(n^2)` runtime if not optimized by the execution engine (which it will probably not do) because of the repeated preceding sibling scans.

---

**Edit**: As stated in the comments, MS SQL doesn't even support the `preceding-sibling` axis. They do support the [`<<` node order comparison operator](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190935(v=sql.105).aspx), though. This query should be fully supported:

```
for $person in /Root/Persons/Person
let $count := count($person/parent::Persons/Person[. << $person]) + 1
return <Person ID="{$count}">{$person}</Person>
```

By the way, you possibly only want to paste the person's name, so better use

```
(: snip :)
return <Person ID="{$count}">{data($person)}</Person>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for answer. In Sql server 2008R2, preceding-sibling is also not supported, the error I've received: Msg 9335, Level 16, State 1, Line 16
XQuery [query()]: The XQuery syntax 'preceding-sibling' is not supported.

Comment: Wow, didn't expect Microsoft had crippled XQuery that much. I extended my answer with another even more ugly workaround which should be supported.

Comment: It works )) The syntax is as ugly as it could be and far from intuitive, but it works )) Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

Another possible formulation that may arguably be easier to read if you are not so familiar with XQuery:

```
for $i in (1 to count(/Root/Persons/Person))
let $person := /Root/Persons/Person[$i]
return
    <Person ID="{$i}">{$person}</Person>
```

Also if SQL Server does/ever support(s) XQuery 3.0, then you could do the following which is rather nice:

```
/Root/Persons/Person ! <Person ID="{position()}">{data(.)}</Person>
```

Comment: Just to compliment: At SQL Server 2005 I am having the error:
The XQuery syntax 'to' is not supported.