# XQuery count iterations in for loop

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, xquery

As far as I can tell the `at` keyword is considered 'standard' XQuery syntax.

```
for $a at $x in //Node/Details
return <node number="{$x}" />
```

For the T-SQL flavor of XQuery this produces the following error.

> XQuery [query()]: The XQuery syntax 'at' is not supported.

How do you count the iterations in a T-SQL XQuery for-loop?

Comment: possible duplicate of [FLWOR in Sql server count number of hits](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18716350/flwor-in-sql-server-count-number-of-hits)

Comment: @RomanPekar confirmed, asked and answered. However, the keywords used in that question aren't very google-able :) Do I delete this?

Comment: Just keep it, it will be closed as duplicate in some time, pointing to the other question. Still might help others having similar problems, but find your post instead.